# Searching for Entities or Umlauts (Filter in DataTables)

Tags: search, filter, entity, datatables, diacritics

I have some issues with the filter/search box in **[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)** ([ZIP-File](http://datatables.net/releases/DataTables-1.10.0.zip)). It ignores Umlauts like ä or ü, I think every "special" character is concerned. I store my strings as entities in the database - to prevent generelly this issue. But the problem, I guess, is processed later, cause the strings are displayed correctly in DataTables' table.

Using the **server-side processing** I have the possibility to encode the strings before (examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php) like

```
array( 'db' => 'Name', 'dt' => 2, 'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) { return html_entity_decode($d, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); } ),
```

...but even WITH OR WITHOUT this addition, I cannot search for the mentioned letters. So probably the filter-string, which is pushed back to the server/database to get the results, is not correct.

Maybe a change in **ssp.class.php** will help? I've already tried to sourround some variables with htmlentities(), but without any luck.

Hopefully you could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is related to the simple server_side/simple.html example in dataTables 1.10.0:

Add this line to the top of scripts/server_processing.php:

```
$_GET['search']['value']=htmlentities($_GET['search']['value'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

This will (hopefully) convert the search request to the same string that is stored in your database.

`ssp.class.php` will construct a mySql Query based on the request parameters. It is essential that you do this conversion **before** the actual db-query happens. The formatter will only work with the result of said query. Since nothing is found, nothing will be formatted:-)

Of course this will only work if your doing a **get** request. If you are using **post** as ajax method you need to change `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

Also this will so far only work for global search. If you are using individual column filtering you also need to convert all `columns[###][search][value]`.

Finally you may need to play around with the encoding, since I am not sure in which encoding your db stores data. (This works with the datatables_demo db).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Thank you also for the detailed explenation! Best regards!